# The "replica trick" initial formula

Tags: statistical-mechanics, spin-models

In [Spin-glass theory for pedestrians](http://iopscience.iop.org/1742-5468/2005/05/P05012) by Castellani and Cavagna, the initial formula used to introduce the replica trick is written as:

$$\overline{\log Z}=\lim_{n\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{n}\log\overline{Z^{n}}\qquad(1)$$

where the overbar denotes average over quenched disorder. I don't know how to prove this formula.

In other treatments I have seen of the replica method ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replica_trick), for example), one starts from:

$$\log Z = \lim_{n\rightarrow 0} \frac{Z^n-1}{n}\qquad(2)$$

which I understand. How are (2) and (1) connected? What's the proof of (1)?

Comment: I think you are missing an $1/n$ in the first equation.

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I realize this thread is old, but I was also reading the "for Pedestrians" introduction and I had the same question. Although the previous response seems reasonable, it does not address the original question. However, using a very similar approach, it is possible to derive (1) from (2).

Let's start from the right hand side of (1):

$$F = \lim_{n \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{n} \log \left( \overline{Z^n} \right),$$

where the overbar denotes average over the quenched disorder. Rewriting (2), we have:

$$Z^n \simeq 1 + n \log Z$$

Inserting into the above expression for $F$ and using the fact that $\overline{1} = 1$, we have:

$$F = \lim_{n \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{n} \log \left( 1 + n \overline { \log Z } \right)$$

Since $n$ is small, we can expand the outer logarithm around $1$ and find:

$$F = \overline{ \log Z }$$

which is the left hand side of (1). This answer was inspired by "Spin Glass Theory and Beyond" by Mezard, Parisi and Virasoro, which I've found to be a very useful resource for this topic.

Comment: Thanks. Do they make this calculation in "Spin glass theory and beyond"? Where?

Comment: If I remember correctly, one of the identities used in the calculation shows up in a footnote early on (the first chapter?)

Comment: They just spit it out in Eqs. I.5 & I.6, but they don't give the explicit derivation... too trival :P

Answer (score 4):

Try to look at *Introduction to the Replica Theory of Disordered Statistical Systems* by V. Dotsenko. In the following, I've written a possible answer to your question:

\begin{equation}
f=-\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\beta N}\mathbb{E}\left[\ln Z_{J}\right]
\end{equation}

where:

- $\mathbb{E}\left[\mathcal{O}\right]=\left(\prod_{\left\{ i,j\right\} }\int dJ_{ij}\right)P\left[J\right]\mathcal{O}
   $
- $Z_{J}=\sum_{\sigma}e^{-\beta H\left[J,\sigma\right]}
   $

Then labelling with $a$ the replicas:
\begin{equation}
Z_{J}^{n}=\left(\prod_{a=1}^{n}\sum_{\sigma^{a}}\right)e^{-\beta\sum_{a=1}^{n}H\left[J,\sigma_{a}\right]}
\end{equation}
Thus, remember that $\ln x=\lim_{n\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{n}\left(x^{n}-1\right)$:
\begin{equation}
f=-\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\beta N}\mathbb{E}\left[\ln\left(Z_{J}\right)\right]=-\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{\beta N}\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\left(Z_{J}^{n}-1\right)}{n}\right]=-\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{n\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{\beta nN}\mathbb{E}\left[Z_{J}^{n}\right]
\end{equation}
but in general there are many issues concerning the commutation of the two limits.

Comment: Why did $\frac 1n$ disappear in the very last step?

Comment: There is $n$ in between $\beta$ and $N$.

Comment: No, but then there should still be a term $\mathbb E [\frac 1n]$, as in $\mathbb E[\frac{Z_J^n -1}n] = \frac 1n E[Z_J^n -1] $

Answer (score 3):

For an even more direct answer to how the two replica tricks you listed are related, simply note that we expect $Z^n \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow 0$. Then,

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{n} \log  \overline{Z^n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{n} \log \Big( 1 + (\overline{Z^n} - 1) \Big) = \lim_{n \rightarrow 0} \frac{\overline{Z^n} - 1}{n} = \overline{\log Z}$$