# Origin of the replica trick

Tags: statistical-mechanics, history, specific-reference, partition-function

The [replica trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replica_trick) consists of the formula:

$$\overline{\log Z}=\lim_{n\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{n}\log\overline{Z^{n}} \tag{1}$$

where $Z$ is the partition function of a system and the overbar denotes an average (see for example [The "replica trick" initial formula?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111950/3064)).

When was this trick used for the first time? Is there an original reference?

Comment: Possibly better on [hsm.se]. I (or another mod) can migrate it if you would like. Just comment to that effect.

Comment: @dmckee Can we leave it here for a few days? If it does not get responses I'll request to migrate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was apparently first done in Section 3 of the following paper (although Edwards used similar ideas in another context, see the paper at the end of this answer for more information):

[S.F. Edwards, P.W. Anderson, *Theory of Spin glasses*, J. Phys. F **5**:965-964, 1975.](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4608/5/5/017)

See [this paper](http://garfield.library.upenn.edu/classics1985/A1985APZ5700001.pdf) for a historical account by one the original authors.

Comment: Thanks. The recollection of Edwards is a nice short read.